# Error trying to run the cubist function on a Kaggle R kernel

Tags: r

I am trying to reproduce the results of an R scrip on the Kaggle R notebook. I have used the caret package to train the Boston House Price Dataset successfully. But when I try to create the final model using the cubist function I get an error message.

```
prepare the data transform using training data
set.seed(7)
x <- dataset[, 1:13]
y <- dataset[, 14]
preprocessParams <- preProcess(x, method = c("BoxCox"))
transX <- predict(preprocessParams, x)
#train the final model
finalModel <- cubist(x = transX, y = y, committeess = 25)

summary(finalModel)

Error in cubist(x = transX, y = y, committeess = 25): could not find function "cubist"
Traceback:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to the my error by importing the Cubist Library

```
library(Cubist)
```

[image]